# ng-controller variables are not visible in directive's link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to read the variables initialised inside ng-controller function in the directive's link function.

Html content - index.html as,

```
<div ng-controller="skCtrl">
     <span sk-custom>click</span>
</div>
```

app.js,

```
app.controller('skCtrl',  function ($scope, $element) {
  $scope.data = "hello world"
})

app.directive("skCustom", function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      data: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
      elem.bind("click", function(){
        //both the statements throw error...
        console.log(data)
        console.log(scope.data)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

When i do a mouse click, it throws error as,

```
data is undefined
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need something in data in directive for example:-

```
<span sk-custom data="name">click</span>
```

Where as in controller i defined name:-

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Directive code:-

```
app.directive("skCustom", function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      data: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
      elem.bind("click", function(){
        //both the statements throw error...
        console.log(scope.data)
      })
    }
  }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bAENaym0l0alRiRhnPC1?p=info)

> data is undefined

It happends because data is not defined in the directive where as scope.data must me pass from directive template.

PS:- scope.$apply(); is required if you change something in scope to run the digest cycle.

Comment: about your statement "You just need something in data in directive ", does data attribute take the variable name that directive uses. If so, how does it work, when the directive uses multiple variables from the controller....

Comment: You need multple attribute for that ex:- `<span sk-custom data="name" data1="abc" check="bcd">click</span> now in directive use data,data1,check and bind it with scope  scope: {
      data: "=",
      data1:"=",
      check:"="
    },`

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an isolate scope with the binding.  You can either remove the `scope:{}` or setup the binding via the directive.

`<sk-custom data="data"></sk-custom>`

you can also use `scope.$parent`, but please only do this if you are absolutely sure as it creates a dependency on the parent scope

Answer (score 0):

The digest cycle is not reached in bind method. So, you need use $apply method:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr){
      elem.bind("click", function(){
        console.log(scope.data);
        scope.$apply();
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ngModel it is default for two way binding

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/4hxfghp1/1/

```
app.directive("skCustom", function(){
  return {
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
      elem.bind("click", function(){
        //both the statements throw error...
        console.log(scope.data)
        console.log(scope)
      })
    }
  }
```

It will give you Hole scope of your controller

Comment: ngModel does nothing in this context.

Comment: it is ok you got solution that is important :D and if you like my answer then you can vote-up

Comment: What I meant was that adding `require: "?ngModel"` does nothing in this case.  Here is a forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8xrxv3L/.  As you can see `scope.data` *does* work because without the isolated scope the directive inherits from the parent scope (in this case the controller).  So the statement, *Use ngModel it is default for two way binding* is simply not true. `ngModel` brings in the `ngModelController` for input elements.